# Pagination with promises after the fact

Tags: javascript, pagination

I've got the following function that I want to paginate, I just found out that the GitHub API only pushes 30 items max through their repos requests;

`getRepos`

```
this.getRepos = function(username, siteAndPassword) {
        // Pagination
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/repos', { 
                auth: { username: username, password: siteAndPassword.password }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
        })
    }
```

Inside of my command line input prompt function `passwordPrompt`'s `.then` call

```
passwordPrompt(site)
            .then((siteAndPassword) => {
                // Auth the user with given password (basic HTTP)
                return API.GitHub.getRepos(user, siteAndPassword)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                process.exit()
            })

.then((repos) => { ... /* Do more crazy stuff with the data */ }
```

Here's my pagination attempt, I set the `per_page` to `1` so I can test it, the function should log currentPage eight times but I just get a blank console.

```
this.getRepos = function(username, siteAndPassword) {
        // Pagination
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var currentPage = 1
            var fullList = []
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/repos', { 
                auth: { username: username, password: siteAndPassword.password },
                params: { page: currentPage, per_page: 1 }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.length == 0) {
                    resolve(fullList)
                } else {
                    console.log(currentPage)
                    currentPage += 1
                    axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/repos', {
                        auth: { username: username, password: siteAndPassword.password },
                        params: { page: currentPage, per_page: 100 }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        response.data.forEach((item) => {
                            fullList.push(item)
                        })
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: I mean it should at least console.log 8 times - the if/else defaults to else unless the returned list is empty - the else makes a new request which appends the new data to fullList - i think (edited it)

Comment: hang on im super confused when it comes to promises - what should I be doing in order to make the loop, remove the inner axios.get and make a helper function, then do a while loop and call it in place of the inner axios.get?

Comment: and then just make sure the inner function gets resolved and checked?

Comment: it's more when you combine loops and asynchronous promises that my brain goes out the window

Comment: oh i think i see what you're saying now - i should be recalling this.getRepos instead of having an inner axios.get edit: or the fiddle

Comment: okay i kind of get it now - but i dont think i'd ever define another promise function in the promise like that - and also what anti-pattern in my promises do you mean, the manual reject/resolve?

Comment: so the return new Promise({ axios.get() }) portions of the code are an anti-pattern - so I should just resolve directly in the .then of my axios.gets (or return)

Comment: that doesn't seem like it would ever be an issue, it would still resolve - but ill do it anyway, thank you for the advice

Comment: you should just return the promise - without a promise constructor, there is no resolve function - it's not **the** issue with your code (as I already said) - the issue with your code is that your code would get 1 item from page 1, then up to 100 items from page 2 - and that's it, and the Promise will never resolve if there's any items to get, because you only ever resolve the returned promise if there are zero items in the first get

Comment: the only issue is then I have to access the `response.data` in a higher function of my code when I just want getRepos to return response.data - that's why I did that

Comment: yeah I know im missing the actual recursion part of my recursive pagination code - i mean the anti pattern being present in the first place; it was to return response.data from the getRepos function instead of accessing it higher up

Comment: well assuming we're just getting the first page

Comment: the recursive stuff ill fix after i fix the anti pattern

Comment: it does resolve just fine (fig 1 in OP) - ill check that fiddle in a bit

Comment: @JaromandaX `does the fiddle jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn work for you?`  - nope, that blanks out the console

Comment: I'm not needing to relax - you misunderstood - I'm removing comments that **haven't helped** - you need to relax yourself, sparky

Comment: You mean like the recursion one, and the anti-pattern one? Very secure.

Comment: `I see the error in my original fiddle, I missed a return - jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/1` - Again, thank you for the help - but I'm going to research recursion more before I just copy people.

Comment: sure, no skin off my nose - the logic in the fiddle is sound, I've dummied up the axios.get call and tested it if you're interested - http://jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/2/

Comment: it seems like it works - but only because you call 100 per_page, try it with 1 per_page - no full recursion

Comment: what?!! your code initially gets 1 per page, I copied **your** logic to only ask for 100 per page if 1 per page results in any data!

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/3/ that doesn't do 1 per page

Comment: yeah - modify that to 1 so we can check if your function recurs down all the way, it should make no difference - but it does edit: different fiddle

Comment: that one new fiddle with way shorter logic works - the old one is for sure broken - this one even works if you set it to 1 per page and length =! 0

Comment: no idea what you are talking about as you talk about "different fiddle" ... different to what?

Comment: working: http://jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/3/ - for sure broken: http://jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/2/

Comment: your new shorter logic one `3` works - the old one `2` was not fixed by you adding your return or whatever you suggested above

Comment: here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/4b2p2ydn/6/ you can play with the total number of "records" and how many per page

Comment: version 2 works fine - it returns 310 "items" numbered 1...310 - exactly like version 3 does ... now, version 6 let's you play with the numbers to see how the **logic** is sound

Comment: version 2, if you try to make it return 1 per page instead of 100, returns only 3 repositories (there should be 8 returned), if you make it 100 per page then it seems like it works because 100 > 8 so you never see it fail. version 3 works amazingly well. version 2 is just impossible to debug

Comment: I'm guessing whatever changes **you** made to version 2 to change from 100 to 1 per page, **you** missed something - because it works fine as long as you remember to change the code correctly (I just tested it)

Comment: i mean i just retested it and simply changing occurrences of `100` to `1` makes it stop going at 3 recursions and return

Comment: well, no it doesn't, not that fiddle - perhaps how you've used that code in your actual code, but I can't test that for you

Comment: maybe it's hitting a github limit, we'll never know - thanks for the help

Comment: `maybe it's hitting a github limit, we'll never know` - well, you should debug the responses and you will know

Comment: ill try that - meanwhile ive got recursion and ternary ifs to research

Comment: the ternary code is just a wank on my part to be able to use the short form of the arrow function syntax ... `param => condition ? v1 : v2` rather than `param => { if (condition) return v1; else return v2; }`

Comment: so the expanded version is like this then https://jsfiddle.net/mm4w6c8v/ and the ternary stuff doesnt really matter

Comment: not quite - you left out a return before `getRecursive(page + 1)`

Comment: oh so if you use a ternary operator there's an implicit `return` after `?` / `:` thats interesting - thank you

Comment: also, I don't check `response.data.length != 0` I check `response.data.length == per_page` - because if you do 100 per page, and get 99 or less, you **know** there is nothing more

Comment: will that mess it up in any way? I feel like the less i hard-code values the better

Comment: no, the implicit return is the short form arrow function ... `var arrowFn = param => returnValue;` which is equivalent to `var arrowFn = param => { return returnValue; };` - the implicit return has nothing to do with ternary op

Comment: no, won't mess anything up, just means one less request in most cases

Comment: oh so it's an implicit return (due to the arrow) of whichever case the ternary if evaluates to, but the ternary if does not implicitly return - gotcha

Comment: alright ill check out using the per_page

Comment: yes, I think you've got it

Comment: brilliant, thanks man